# Trouble using AsyncTask outside of Activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I've created an AsyncTask as inner class of my activity. And this works good.

But now, since I want reuse this AsyncTask inside many other activity, I'm trying to use a separate class for the AsyncTask.

The problem is that now I lost all the context reference. So, for example the code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(myActvity.this, "Wait...", "sending data ...", true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
```

can't work, since the context in the show method cannot be resolved.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: did you pass `Context` from activity to the `Asynctask`?

Comment: No, how can I pass it? Can I simple define a costructor in which I can pass it?

Comment: `I'm trying to use a separate class for the AsyncTask.` use separate class constructor for getting Activity Context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

create your AsyncTask class in following way :-

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

  private Context mContext; // context reference 
  private ProgressDialog pDialog;

  public MyTask(Context context){ //constructor 
   this.mContext = context;
  }

 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "Wait...", "sending data ...", true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
```

and use it :-

```
MyTask mTask = new MyTask(Activity.this);
mTask.execute();
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass a context in the constructor of the Async task class. e.g you could define your AsynTask class constructor like this:

```
     public MyAsyncTask(Context con){
           this.context = con;
     }
```

and then pass it the context of the activity you are calling your async task from.

```
    MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(CurrentActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :
from where you are calling task :

```
YourAsyncTaskTaskClass task = new YourAsyncTaskTaskClass(activityContext);
task.execute();
```

inside your thread class :

```
Context context;
    public YourAsyncTaskTaskClass(Context context) {
        this.contex = context;
    }
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        d = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Wait...", "sending data ...", true);
    }
```